# iOS - Is video/image on server portrait or landscape?

Tags: ios, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller, alasset

If a user uploads a video to a server and I later try to play it with an MPMoviePlayerController from the remote url, how do I know if the video was originally taken in portrait or landscape mode? Same for an image. I need to set the view frame based on the orientation of the original asset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MPMoviePlayerController` reports the `naturalSize`. If the `naturalSize.width > naturalSize.height`, you've got a landscape video.

Similarly, a `UIImage` reports a `size`. If the `size.width > size.height`, you've got a landscape image.

Comment: Thanks. When does it report this? I tried right after initWithContentURL but the size is 0.0, 0.0 at that point.